# CLIPS finding facts not working

Tags: clips

I have the following deftemplates in CLIPS (6.3):

```
(deftemplate A ( slot a ) (slot b) )
(deftemplate forSearch (slot property)(slot value))
```

I need to read the pair `(property, value)` from input, and then find the fact `A` whose value in the slot `property` is `value`.

If I do something like this:

```
(defrule r2
(forSearch (property ?c)(value ?d))
(A (?c ?d))
=>
(printout t "debug" crlf)
)
```

I get the following error:

```
[PRNTUTIL2] Syntax Error:  Check appropriate syntax for deftemplate patterns.

ERROR:
(defrule MAIN::r2
   (forSearch (property ?c) (value ?d))
   (A (?c
```

What should I do now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to write to slot name in the pattern matching part of the rule.

The correct sintax is:

```
(defrule r2
     (forSearch (property ?c)(value ?d))
     (A (a ?c) (b ?d))
     =>
     (printout t "debug" crlf)
)
```

I don't understand what you want to accomplish, and I know it's late, but hope it helps.

Comment: It appears that he wants to be able to specify the `A` slot to be matched using the `forSearch` deftemplate so that there wouldn't need to be separate rules for each slot.  That is, `?c` could specify either slot `a` or slot `b`.

Comment: I don't think that's possible, according to the CLIPS manual, a wildcard cannot be the first item in a pattern.